How get job outputs for the transitive dependency in GitHub workflow
I am struggling with accessing the specific job outputs from previous steps that have a transitive dependency. For example:
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build Application
    runs-on:
      - ubuntu-22.04
    container:
      image: some-image
    outputs:
      POM_VERSION: ${{ steps.variables.outputs.POM_VERSION }}
      JAR_PROJECT_VERSION: ${{ steps.variables.outputs.JAR_PROJECT_VERSION }}
    steps:
      // ... steps, with some populating outputs

  somethingElse:
    name: Build Application
    needs:
      - build
    runs-on:
      - ubuntu-22.04
    container:
      image: some-image
    steps:
      // ... some steps


  somethingElseAgain:
    name: Build Application
    needs:
      - somethingElse
    runs-on:
      - ubuntu-22.04
    container:
      image: some-image
    steps:
      // ... steps, trying to access {{needs.build.outputs.JAR_PROJECT_VERSION}}

My problem arises in somethingElseAgain where I try to access build steps output without putting it into needs. By, reasonably speaking, build is a dependency due to transitivity of somethingElse. Is there a way to access build's outputs without placing it into needs, since this makes visualization graph a bit messy?

Not unless somethingElse explicitly forwards them, I don't think.
